# Sum of primes below two million using three methods on Python

Tags: python, sum, primes

This question is simple but this time, I'm required to use three different methods instead of just one. They are: isPrime, getPrimes, sumPrimes.

This is my original:

```
import sys
print("")

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

prime_sum = 0
for i in range(2, 10): #change 10 back to 2000000
     if is_prime(i):
      prime_sum += i

print ("Sum of all the primes below 10 = ", prime_sum)
```

My issue is how can I get the above statement  starting with prime_sum = 0 to work within a different such as sumPrimes? I tried doing this:

```
def sum_primes():
    prime_sum = 0
    for i in range(2, 10): #change 10 back to 2000000
     if is_prime(i):
      prime_sum += i

    #print ("Sum of all the primes below 2,000,000 = ", prime_sum)
print ("Sum of all the primes below 10 = ", prime_sum)
return sum_primes()
```

Yet it doesn't work. I'm new to Python, so I would appreciate some feedback. Thanks.

Comment: you have to _return `prime_sum` in the end... and consider a sieve of erathostenes to generate prime list to 2 millon. Much faster.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is **not an adequate problem statement**. Also, those are just *functions* and they are not *methods*.

Answer (score 0):

You blew the stack because you call **sum_primes** recursively with no base case.  This is infinite recursion.  As M. Fabre already pointed out, you have to return your accumulated sum, rather than recurring.  Also, your indentation is faulty.  Try this:

```
def sum_primes():
    prime_sum = 0
    for i in range(2, 10): #change 10 back to 2000000
      if is_prime(i):
        prime_sum += i

    #print ("Sum of all the primes below 2,000,000 = ", prime_sum)
    print ("Sum of all the primes below 10 = ", prime_sum)
    return prime_sum

sum_primes()
```

Also, as you about to discover, generating all those primes by individual inspection and exhaustive division is a very slow process.  Look up how to generate primes in Python; there will be completed solutions all over the first page of hits.  Even the probabilistic methods work perfectly through 2 million, and those are *fast*.

I now have a solution sum of

```
142913828922
```